# Layout Constraint Violation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

AppName[2338:563134] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16663190 V:[UIView:0x16663310(48)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16662f80 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x16663310]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x16663400 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16662ef0 V:[UIView:0x166637e0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x16663400 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16662ec0 V:[UIView:0x16663310]-(1)-[UIView:0x166637e0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16639fb0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x16663400(10)]>"
```

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

The result for **UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints** shows

```
UIWindow:0x166a1d80
|   UILayoutContainerView:0x1658a4c0
|   |   UINavigationTransitionView:0x165a1970
|   |   |   UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x166bf650
|   |   |   |   •UIView:0x16665c30
|   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x166678e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x165f95a0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   •UIView:0x16557350
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *Charts.BarChartView:0x17366800
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x16557260
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x16557520'labeltext'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x16557940'04/05/2016'
|   |   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x1665eec0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   •UIView:0x165459e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *Charts.BarChartView:0x16b60800
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x165458f0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x16545bd0'labeltext'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x16545e50
|   |   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x1665dce0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   •UIView:0x1664dd10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *Charts.BarChartView:0x17308a00
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x1664dc20
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x1664df00'labeltext'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x1664e180
|   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x16665b70
|   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x16665ab0
|   |   |   |   |   |   *home:0x1666ae80
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x166677e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x16665f10
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x16669400
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x166659a0'labeltext'
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x1666c4f0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x1655ec10
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x16665670
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x166679a0'labeltext'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x1666c390
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x1655e7b0
|   |   |   |   |   DrawingArea:0x16655440
|   |   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x1664a8f0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x1664a9b0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x1664fca0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x1664fd80
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x1664fe60


I  made a trace for **po [[0x16663310 superview] recursiveDescription]** which is giving me

"UIView: 0x16663400; frame = (500 385; 10 10); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = CALayer: 0x166633d0"
   | "UIView: 0x16663310; frame = (0 0; 10 9); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = CALayer: 0x166632e0"
   |    | "UIButton: 0x166764f0; frame = (-30 -12; 32 33); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = CALayer: 0x16665890"
   |    |    | "UIImageView: 0x178a5b70; frame = (0 0; 32 32); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = CALayer: 0x1663c0c0"
   |    | "UILabel: 0x16663550; frame = (8 5; 0 0); text = ''; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x1666d660"
   | <UIView: 0x166637e0; frame = (0 10; 10 0); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = CALayer: 0x16663520>>.
```

Can't really make out anything of this as to how to resolve this thing.
Please help

[Document Outline of the Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xHwr.png)

Comment: can u give the constraints you set on the interface builder?

Comment: Sudheer, thank you for the edit..can you help me with this?

Comment: @Mathews, i can't really make out which view is to be looked into. Can you take me there? Sorry i am new to this..

Comment: is there multiple views in the controller scene? can u post an image of the Document Outline of the scene? This seems to be a constraint violation of a UIView. check for UIViews in the scene

Comment: Please go through https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html. This will help you in understanding these logs

Comment: as for the question, the system generates a `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` which should always take precedence. If you lower the priority of the conflicting constraints to 999 or any value less than 1000, everything should work as expected. Please try.

Comment: the log is getting generated when i am trying to call a method on the parent from it's child for capturing an image of what is shown on the screen/UIScreen and saving the image in the form of NSData.
The preview of the display shows the image but when i capture it on the child view, the log generates and NSData object show some random bites.
@GoGreen, please let me know how can i change the priority.

Comment: @Mathews, i have shared the Document Outline as well. Please find the hyperlink in the question. Document Outline of the Scene

Comment: You have set the Top and Center Y constraints for the View. Please avoid one and check if it solve the issue. Also the `SpacerV` is found to have two `Leading Constraints`. Just 4 constraints are needed for any item in `StoryBoard` to determine `1. X-position` `2. Y-Position` `3. Width` `4. Height`. Don't add multiple constraints that could possibly make the compiler doubtful in determining any of these four.

Comment: @Daansh The logs are shown in visual format language. V stands for vertical constraints. From what I can see, you have a view with height constraint 48, Top  and bottom constraints 0 with its superview. Vertical spacing of 1 with another view, and an encapsulated-layout-height constraint which is system generated. Change the priority of all other constraints mentioned here to 999.

Comment: For changing the priority, select a constraint from the storyboard or document outline. In the attributes inspector in the right side pane, you can find an attribute named 'priority' with value 1000. change this to 999.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?